# Llamar a una funcionalidad javascript desde html

Tags: javascript, html

Necesito llamar a la función editProduct() desde un botón en el html. Lo que hice fué agregarle al botón onclick="editProduct()". Éste es el código javascript:

```js
const API = (function() {
  /**
   * Obtiene una orden desde el backend
   *
   * @param {Number} orderId id de la orden
   */
  function getOrder(orderId) {
    return fetch('/order/1')
      .then(function toJson(r) {
        return r.json();
      });
  }

  /**
   * Obtiene todos los productos desde el backend
   *
   */
  function getProducts() {
    return fetch('/product')
      .then(function toJson(r) {
        return r.json();
      });
  }

  /**
   * Obtiene todos los productos pertenecientes a una orden desde el backend
   *
   */
  function getOrderProduct(orderId, productId) {
    return fetch(`/order/${ orderId }/product/${ productId }`)
      .then(function toJson(r) {
        return r.json();
      });
  }

  /**
   * Edita un producto de una orden
   *
   */
  function editProduct(orderId, productId, quantity, product) {
    const data = JSON.stringify({
      quantity: quantity,
      product: product
    })

    return fetch(`/order/${ orderId }/product/${ productId }`, {
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: data
    }).then(function toJson(r) {
      return r.json();
    });
  }

  /**
   * Agrega un producto a una orden
   **/
  function addProduct(orderId, product, quantity) {
    const data = JSON.stringify({
      quantity: quantity,
      product: product
    })

    return fetch(`/order/${ orderId }/product`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: data
    }).then(function toJson(r) {
      return r.json();
    });
  }

  return {
    getOrder,
    getProducts,
    getOrderProduct,
    editProduct,
    addProduct
  }
})()
```

```html
<button onclick="editProduct()">Botón</button>
```

Aclaro además que el archivo se encuentra en static/js/api.js

Comment: Hola Luis, te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español. Completa el [tour] para aprender cómo funciona el sitio en general y lee [ask] donde encontrarás consejos sobre cómo mejorar tus preguntas.

Comment: Además lee sobre cómo crear un [mcve]. En muchas de las preguntas de programación web se puede incluir un ejemplo ejecutable que permite al resto de usuarios ver el problema, y de ese modo pueden identificar la causa y ayudarte con una solución.

Answer (score 2):

El metodo `editProduct()` es privado al funcion anomina `(function(){ ... })`
pero el evento `onclick` espera que sea publica. Tienes hacer la funcion public para que el onclick pueda acceder a ella:

```
cons API = (function(){
  window.editProduct = function(){
    //...
  }
});
```

---

Aunque entiendo que lo que quieres es poder acceder a la funcion en la forma `API.editProduct()`. Para eso tendras que crear la forma en como lo declaras utilizando un objeto:

```
var API = {
  editProduct : function(){
    //...
 }
};
```

Y entonces puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
<button onclick="API.editProduct()">Editar producto</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que no estás definiendo la función `editProduct` en sí, sino un objeto (`API`) que contiene diversas funciones (siendo `editProduct` una de ellas). Entonces para acceder a las diferentes funciones, no las llamarías directamente haciendo `onclick="editProduct()"` sino que tendrías que acceder a la función del objeto/API que has creado: `onclick="API.editProduct()"`

Con ese cambio, ya funcionará:

```js
const API = (function() {
  /**
   * Obtiene una orden desde el backend
   *
   * @param {Number} orderId id de la orden
   */
  function getOrder(orderId) {
    return fetch('/order/1')
      .then(function toJson(r) {
        return r.json();
      });
  }

  /**
   * Obtiene todos los productos desde el backend
   *
   */
  function getProducts() {
    return fetch('/product')
      .then(function toJson(r) {
        return r.json();
      });
  }

  /**
   * Obtiene todos los productos pertenecientes a una orden desde el backend
   *
   */
  function getOrderProduct(orderId, productId) {
    return fetch(`/order/${ orderId }/product/${ productId }`)
      .then(function toJson(r) {
        return r.json();
      });
  }

  /**
   * Edita un producto de una orden
   *
   */
  function editProduct(orderId, productId, quantity, product) {
    console.log("Dentro de EditProduct");
    const data = JSON.stringify({
      quantity: quantity,
      product: product
    })

    return fetch(`/order/${ orderId }/product/${ productId }`, {
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: data
    }).then(function toJson(r) {
      return r.json();
    });
  }

  /**
   * Agrega un producto a una orden
   **/
  function addProduct(orderId, product, quantity) {
    const data = JSON.stringify({
      quantity: quantity,
      product: product
    })

    return fetch(`/order/${ orderId }/product`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: data
    }).then(function toJson(r) {
      return r.json();
    });
  }

  return {
    getOrder,
    getProducts,
    getOrderProduct,
    editProduct,
    addProduct
  }
})()
```

```html
<button onclick="API.editProduct()">Botón</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

No pude hacerlo funcionar. Entiendo que el archivo api.js lo usa index.js para cargar un producto por ejemplo. Pero no puedo editar uno cargado. Este es el código:
https://github.com/luis-sama/ord

Comment: no debes  usar una respuesta para responder a otra, utiliza en cambio la sección de comentarios